# Line Breaks with Wordpress Preview Images and Bootstrap

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, line-breaks

I'm currently working on a wordpress theme with bootstrap and I can't figure out how to set up line breaks on my posts when in mobile view.
I want to have at least upwards of 4-5 words on the right side of my preview image (currently it even displays single words on the right side which looks silly)
[image: Line Breaks]

The code for my frontpage looks like this:

```
<div class="content">

  <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

      <div class="row"><!-- Row Start -->

        <div class="col-xs-12">

          <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">

          <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() )
          echo '<div class="post_thumb">' . get_the_post_thumbnail(null, 'medium') . '</div>';
          ?>
          <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Weiter zum kompletten Beitrag</a>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="row trenner">
        <div class="col-xs-12"><hr></div>
      </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches you can apply, 1st one is to decrease image width as per your needs and your content will automatically be there as you want. Or you can add you image full width and all your content will be below your thumbnail. For that you have to apply this below given style.

```
.post_thumb {
display: block;
text-align: center;
}
```

Its upto you now, which one suits you.

Answer (score 0):

the image is too large for accommodating 4-5 words on the right of it so use thumbnail ( or set an image size of a width that suits the design concept of yours )instead of medium as the 2nd argument of get_the_post_thumbnail